Is "remove something for someone" acceptable in written English?
I'm not a native English speaker, and I don't know whether "remove something for someone" is correct or not; in my context it would be "You are about to remove StackExchange access for John Smith".
I think the correct sentence would be "You are about to remove StackExchange access from John Smith" but I'm not sure if both ways are accepted.

"for" suggests a benefit, "from" suggests a privation. You could certainly remove somebody's rubbish for them. I guess being banned from StackExchange could be considered a good thing? (COCA has one hit for "remove access for" and none for "remove access from" but that can't be considered statistically significant.)

I laughed, thanks :D But joke aside, I saw that Google uses it (https://support.google.com/a/answer/9178892?hl=en) so it is probably be fine.

No, it doesn't sound right. "You are about to remove John Smith's access to Stack Exchange".
